# Impala + parquet file

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, impala, parquet

I have created creating parquet file and then I am trying to import it into Impala table.

I created table as below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `user_daily` (
`user_id` BIGINT COMMENT 'User ID',
`master_id` BIGINT,
`walletAgency` BOOLEAN,
`zone_id` BIGINT COMMENT 'Zone ID',
`day` STRING COMMENT 'The stats are aggregated for single days',
`clicks` BIGINT COMMENT 'The number of clicks',
`impressions` BIGINT COMMENT 'The number of impressions',
`avg_position` BIGINT COMMENT 'The average position * 100',   
`money` BIGINT COMMENT 'The cost of the clicks, in hellers',
`web_id` BIGINT COMMENT 'Web ID',
`discarded_clicks` BIGINT COMMENT 'Number of discarded clicks from   column "clicks"',
`impression_money` BIGINT COMMENT 'The cost of the impressions, in hellers'
)
PARTITIONED BY (
 year BIGINT,
 month BIGINT
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/warehouse/impala/contextstat.db/user_daily/';
```

Then I copy files there with this schema:

```
parquet-tools schema user_daily/year\=2016/month\=8/part-r-00001-fd77e1cd-c824-4ebd-9328-0aca5a168d11.snappy.parquet 
message spark_schema {
  optional int32 user_id;
  optional int32 web_id (INT_16);
  optional int32 zone_id;
  required int32 master_id;
  required boolean walletagency;
  optional int64 impressions;
  optional int64 clicks;
  optional int64 money;
  optional int64 avg_position;
  optional double impression_money;
  required binary day (UTF8);
}
```

And then when I try to see entries with

```
SELECT * FROM user_daily;
```

I get

```
File 'hdfs://.../warehouse/impala/contextstat.db/user_daily/year=2016/month=8/part-r-00000-fd77e1cd-c824-4ebd-9328-0aca5a168d11.snappy.parquet' 
has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 'contextstat.user_daily.user_id'. 
Column type: BIGINT, Parquet schema:
optional int32 user_id [i:0 d:1 r:0]
```

Do you know how to solve this problem? I think that BIGINT is the same as int_32. Should I change scheme of table or generating of parquet files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `CAST(... AS BIGINT)`, which change parquet schema from `int32` to `int64`. Then I have to reorder of columns because it wont join then by name. Then it works.

Answer (score 3):

BIGINT is int64, that's why it complains. But you don't necessarily have to figure out the different types that you have to use yourself, Impala can do that for you. Just use the [CREATE TABLE LIKE PARQUET](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_create_table.html) variant:

> The variation CREATE TABLE ... LIKE PARQUET 'hdfs_path_of_parquet_file' lets you skip the column definitions of the CREATE TABLE statement. The column names and data types are automatically configured based on the organization of the specified Parquet data file, which must already reside in HDFS.

Comment: Unfortunately this way of solution is not what I need. There is certain table with structure show above and I would like to stick with solution where I change parquet files. BTW: I try it ... next error occurs : `ERROR: AnalysisException: Unsupported logical parquet type INT_16 (primitive type is INT32) for field web_id`

Comment: The error message shows that there is no type that you could specify in the table definition that would be compatible with what the Parquet file contains. If you would like to stick to the table definition and change the Parquet schema, then simply change all instances of `int32` to `int64` and remove the `(INT_16)` part.

Comment: But how can I remove `(INT_16)` part from that scheme? It is shown after calling `parquet-tools scheme` and it describes already existing file? Is there a way to change it in already existing file?

Comment: When you said "I would like to stick with solution where I change parquet files", I thought that you generate the Parquet files and you want to change that process. If you are working with already existing Parquet files, you can't change their schema.

Comment: yes, you are right. The solution with changing parquet file/schema is acceptable. I hope that changing it will be easy :D.